# Lotus notes client link and browser link in xpages to download file stored in server directory

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I have a Xpage in which there is a link to download the ics file which I have stored on server,As when the user clicks the link, the user is able to download the file name "votes.ics".

Accordingly when it is been accessed from browser, it allows me to download the file but at the same time when I want to download the same file using the link from LOTUS NOTES Client,It throws as an error Resource file not found it means the path in notes client has an issue,

To make it more clear, For example I have a database name "SMP_Intern.nsf" in the folder name "SMP" on the server and the onclick script behind the link is

```
var docId = getVotingDocumentUID();
if(docId != ""){
if(@ClientType() == "Notes"){
var path_private = "server_name/SMP/SMP_Intern.nsf";
var httpUrl = path_private.split("/")[0];
var databaseUrl = (httpUrl+"!!"+path_private.split("/")[1]+"/"+path_private.split("/")[2]);
var url = "/xsp/"+databaseUrl+"/.ibmmodres/domino/OpenAttachment/"+databaseUrl+"/"+docId+"/ics_file/votes.ics";
return url;
}else{
var url = "/0/"+docId+"/$File/"+"votes"+".ics?OpenElement";
return url;
}
}else return false;
```

For the notes client it goes to 'if' condition and gives error resource not found,but when it is browser the 'else' condition works perfectly fine.

Both the paths are same basically but could not able to find the mistake.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a special treatment for Notes Client (XPiNC) in this case.

Your SSJS code for link value

```
var url = "/0/"+docId+"/$File/"+"votes"+".ics?OpenElement";
return url;
```

works for XPiNC too as the attachment is in the current database:
If current database resides on server then the URL points to the attachment on server.
If current database is a local replica then the URL points to the attachment in local database on client.

Comment: I have tried with the same but unfortunately Its give me Error 500.

Comment: In this case after some research I found that if I have that, if the database name(SMP_Intern) and the folder name(SMP) is in lower case it worked. but if it is in Upper case it return the same error that resource file not found.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried @URLOpen( urlstring )formula for opening from client ?

The url must be a complete url http://DominoServer/DBPath/0/DocUNID/$file/filename

var url = "http://"+path_private +"/0/"+docId+"/$File/"+"votes"+".ics?OpenElement";

@URLOpen( url );

Comment: In notes client when we have an http link, it would ask you for a login instead of taking the notes credentials. Thats the reason I have different link for notes and browser